# How to merge two fields into one field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Below are the product collection sample docs :

```
{ _id:'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  name:'product 1'
 }
{ _id:'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  name:'product 2'
 }
```

how to group id field value to name field value in mongodb?

**Expected result :**

```
[{'xxxxxxxxxxxx:'product1'},{'xxxxxxxxxxxx':'product2'}]
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: What is the type of `_id` if it's of type `ObjectId()` you can't do this you need to convert it to string in-order to do it as keys doesn't hold `ObjectId()`'s..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation queries :

On MongoDB version >= `4.2`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $arrayToObject: [
        [
          {
            k: { $toString: "$_id" },
            v: "$name"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xwZE8gmKkS9)

On MongoDB version >= `4.0` :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: [
          [
            {
              k: { $toString: "$_id" },
              v: "$name"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lZpMFD0n2tO)

Just in case if you've more fields & wanted to retain all of those in document in the final result then try this on MongoDB version >= `4.0` :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            $arrayToObject: [ [ { k: { $toString: "$_id" }, v: "$name" } ] ]
          },
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y8jmLnaNM5T)

**Note :** As keys in an object must be of type `string` & can't hold type of `ObjectId()` We're converting `_id` value to `string`, if your `_id` is of type string then no need to use `$toString` operator.

**Ref :** [aggregation-pipeline-stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)